# DJANGO - convert POST data to JSON and render HTML partially

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, django, ajax

I'm stuck trying to convert data from the AJAX call to `view.py` and back to HTML:

JQuery/Javascript

```js
    function getCookie(name) {
        var cookieValue = null;
        if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
            var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                var cookie = cookies[i].trim();
                // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                    cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return cookieValue;
    }

    function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
        // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
        return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){ 

        var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

        $.ajaxSetup({
            beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
                if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
                }
            }
        });

        // AJAX CALL TO VIEW
        $('a.play').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var song_id = $(this).attr('id');
            alert(song_id);
            $.ajax({
                url: $(this).data('href'),
                type: 'POST',
                content: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                data: {
                    'song_id': song_id
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(html) {
                    alert(html);
                    $('.player').replaceWith(html);
                },
            });
        });
    });
```

views.py

```py
    from django.shortcuts import render
    from django.http import Http404, JsonResponse
    from django.core import serializers
    from django.template.loader import render_to_string

    from .models import Song

    def change_song(request):
        if request.method == "POST":
            request.session['featured_song'] = request.POST.get('song_id', '')
            featured_song_id = request.session['featured_song']
            obj = Song.objects.get(pk=featured_song_id)
            song_list = Song.objects.all().order_by('-date') # list of objects
        context = {
            "featured_song": obj,
            "song_list": song_list,
        }
        return render_to_string("music/player.html", context)
```

Therefore, after receiving the POST for the AJAX call, I try to return it to alert its content (debugging). The first alert `song_id` returns the id as it should, the second does not even run. When trying to debug (I don't remember the exact situation), when it runs, the second `alert()` just returns the WHOLE html page, not just the portion.

NOTES:
`music/player.html` on the view is basically the `.player` container. It is void of includes or extends or blocks that extend other templates.

Comment: Not seeing any alerts.

Comment: Why not just return a JSON object and replace the data in the current HTML? You can use JSonResponse https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects

Comment: Sorry. The alerts where before the call and after success. Forgot to edit. The JSON response returns the WHOLE HTML page, including headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I ended up resolving the issue. It was an template/url issue all along...

I was trying to access the sub APP url path `href="/change/"` and didn't fill the complete URL for the APP `href="/music/change/"`. My thought process was that, since the template was inside the template folder in 'music' APP, the URL only needed the `/change/` part of the URL.

That being said, I will still post the code here for future reference since I also fixed some JSON handling, in case someone needs to use something similar.

views.py

```
def change_song(request):
    featured_song_id = request.session['featured_song']
    song_list = Song.objects.all().order_by('-date') # list of objects
    if request.method == "POST":
        request.session['featured_song'] = request.POST['song_id']
        featured_song_id = request.session['featured_song']
    obj = Song.objects.get(pk=featured_song_id)
    serialized_obj = serializers.serialize('json', [obj])
    serialized_song_list = serializers.serialize('json', song_list)
    string_render = render_to_string('music/player.html')
    context = {
        'html': string_render,
        'obj': serialized_obj,
        'song_list': serialized_song_list,
    }
    return JsonResponse(context, safe=False)
```

AJAX/jQuery/Javascript

```
    $('a.play').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var song_id = $(this).attr('id');
        var this_url = $(this).attr('href');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: this_url,
            data: {
                'song_id': song_id,
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                obj = JSON.parse(data.obj);
                title = obj[0]['fields']['title'];
                $('.replace').replaceWith(data.html);
                $('.player-title').html(title);
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parse the ajax call json, do the following in your view:

```
        if request.method == "POST":
            content = request.body.decode('utf-8')
            data = json.loads(content)
            request.session['featured_song'] = data.get('song_id', '')
            featured_song_id = request.session['featured_song']
```

Comment: Still have the same response on /music/change: the whole html page. The views' is directed to /music. Could that be a problem?